# Regex: Extract string between two strings

Tags: regex, jmeter

This is the issue I face

**The String**

> nt/sign-in?wa=wsignin1.0&wtre

**The Need**

From that string I need to extract the following

- wsignin1.0

**The Attempts**

So far I have tried the following Regex

```
wa=(.*?)(?=&amp)
```

This returns:

> wa=wsignin1.0

The "wa=" is not supposed to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with a look behind?

```
(?<=wa\=)(.+)(?=\&wtre)
```

> wsignin1.0

Comment: Yeah that worked. But I edited it a bit (?<=wa=)(.*)(?=&amp;wtrealm)

Answer (score 1):

JMeter uses [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) therefore the regex you are looking for might be as simple as:

```
wa=(.+?)&wtre
```

Demo:

[image: Regex URL Extract]

Use `$1$` as "Template" in your Regular Expresssion Extractor.

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more details on JMeter tests troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

```
=([\w.]++)
```

will capture it in the first capture group. Otherwise I think @jivan has a good idea with the lookbehind. A little tweak too it:

```
(?<==)[\w.]++
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Regular Expression extractor:

```
nt/sign-in?wa=([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)&wtre
```

[image]
I hope this help you.