# How to extract value form json using Regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

How to extract token values from below code response using RegEx:

```
{"status":"Success","message":"Successful logged in!","data":{"email":"some@gmail.com","full_name":"full name","token":"some token","someotherparam":"something"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex as shown in the [example](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=112949)

```
(?<=("|')token("|'):("|'))(.*?)(?=("|'))
```

But I would recommend using some function like json_decode() and retrieve the array.

Comment: it is also selecting last double quote

Comment: I'm getting this error on JMeter "org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: (?<=("|')token("|'):("|'))(.*?)("|')(=?) Sequence (?<...) not recognized"

Comment: I see, I checked now the user manual on JMeter https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html and it doesn't support this expression, please stay tuned while I check another one.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795568/regex-extract-string-between-two-strings-no-apparent-delimitors