# Regular Expression in JMeter throws an error where as it is working in fine regex tester

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have response from previous request. I am trying to use regular expression to get the required text. My response is given below

```
{
  "screen": {
    "heading": "HEADING",
    "content": {
      "lines": [
        "Scan the source CBSE. "
      ]
    },
    "prompt": {
      "default": "",
      "display_value": "HEADING",
      "masked": {
        "on": "FALSE",
        "char": "*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above json response i am trying to extract the word **CBSE** . I am using the below regular expression in regex tester - **(?<=Scan the source ).*(?=. ")**

But when i check the same in JMeter i am getting error and it is not saved in the variable too.

Error in JMeter:
org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: (?<=Scan the source ).*(?=. ")
Sequence (?<...) not recognized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: Extract string between two strings. No apparent delimitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795568/regex-extract-string-between-two-strings-no-apparent-delimitors)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think your regex is valid for [Jakarta ORO](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/) syntax, try something more simple like:

```
"Scan the source\s*(.+?)\. "
```

[image]

Also be aware that JMeter provides [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) so it's sufficient to just supply "left" and "right" boundaries and JMeter will get everything in-between:

[image]

Moreover this approach consumes less resources, see [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) article for more information.